# How to debug playwright in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, debugging, playwright

I've tried to debug like descript in docu:

```
Windows with cmd.exeset PWDEBUG=consolenpm run test

Windows with PowerShell$env:PWDEBUG="console"npm run test
```

Therefore I've tried in ubuntu:

```
PWDEBUG=console npm run test
```

This also doesn't work.

How is the right way to debug in Windows 10?

Next, I've tried the following command in ubuntu:

```
PWDEBUG=1 npx playwright test
```

This worked in Ubuntu but not in Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

If you're using visual studio code the default terminal is powershell.
You can open this by going to menu bar: `Terminal` > `New Terminal`

If you're not using VS code, just open a new powershell window from the start menu.

You'll know it's powershell as the terminal line start with "PS".

You need to kick off the debugger with two lines. One to turn on the debugger and one to run the tests:

```
$env:PWDEBUG=1
npx playwright test --headed --browser=chromium
```

That second lines runs everything as I create this folder with just 1 test file. Refer to the [CLI](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-cli/) if you want to run a specific tests

VS Code with the terminal window looks like this:
[image: VS Code terminal debug lines]

When you run the second line that opens the playwright inspector to allow you to debug:
[image: playwright debug window]

Answer (score 0):

one liner works for me from VSCode terminal:
`set $env:PWDEBUG=1 && npx playwright test --headed --browser=chromium`